# How to recall a function until invalid input?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and I was wondering how I could recall a function until the user gives invalid input.
Here's a sample of code:

```
start = input("For sum of squares, type 'squares'. For sum of cubes, type 'cubes'. "
              "\nIf you would like to raise a number to something other than 'squares' or 'cubes', type 'power'. "
              "\nIf you would like to exit, type 'exit':")

def main_function(start):
    while start.lower() != "exit":
        if start.lower() in "squares":
            initial = input("What is the initial constant for the sum of the squares: ")
            terms = input("Number of terms: ")

        if start.lower() in "cubes":
            initial = input("What is the initial constant for the the sum of the cubes: ")
            terms = input("Number of terms: ")



           if start.lower() in "power":
                initial = input("What is the initial constant for the the sum: ")
                terms = input("Number of terms: ")

        else:
            print("Program halted normally.")
            quit()

main_function(start)
```

What I am trying to get it to do is to reprompt 'start' if the user inputs a proper input, and then get it to run through the function again. I have tried putting 'start' within the function above and below the 'else' statement, but it never accepts the new input.

Comment: Use a loop -- while loops work best for user input

Comment: Thats what i have been using, unless you mean add another while loop within the while loop?

Comment: @user7433120 Bingo :)

Comment: @user7433120: Yes. You may want to put the logic of the main loop into a separate function so it is a bit more logical.

Comment: @dawg So should I make the new while loop as a separate function for readability and organization?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this, define the start input in a method and call it inside the loop, when it's equal to `"exit"` than break the loop.

Also use `elif`, this way if the first condition statement is True than you won't check the others, unless that what you want of course.

```
def get_start_input():
    return input("For sum of squares, type 'squares'. For sum of cubes, type 'cubes'. "
              "\nIf you would like to raise a number to something other than 'squares' or 'cubes', type 'power'. "
              "\nIf you would like to exit, type 'exit':")

def main_function():
    while True:
        start = get_start_input()
        if start.lower() == "squares":
            initial = input("What is the initial constant for the sum of the squares: ")
            terms = input("Number of terms: ")

        elif start.lower() == "cubes":
            initial = input("What is the initial constant for the the sum of the cubes: ")
            terms = input("Number of terms: ")

        elif start.lower() == "power":
            initial = input("What is the initial constant for the the sum: ")
            terms = input("Number of terms: ")

        elif start.lower() == "exit":
            print("Program halted normally.")
            break

main_function()
```

**EDIT:**

As  dawg  wrote in comment, it's preferred to use here `==`  instead of `in` because you can have several matches and ambiguous meanings.

Comment: Works great! Thanks

Comment: Instead of `in` use `start=="squares"[0:len(start)]` (for example) Otherwise you will have ambiguous matches that are hard to debug. Also, just do one `start=start.lower()` at the start of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help and knowledge! It will help me down the road